# $p$-adic logarithm is a homomorphism, formal power series proof

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

Consider the $p$-adic logarithm defined by the series
$$\log (1+x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^n}{n}.$$
It converges for $|x|_p < 1$, and if $|x|_p < 1$ and $|y|_p < 1$, then we have
$$\log ((1+x)\cdot (1+y)) = \log (1+x) + \log (1+y).$$
One way to show it is to note that in the ring of formal power series $\mathbb{Q} [[X,Y]]$ (where $\log (1+X)$ is defined by the same formula) we have
$$\log ((1+X)\cdot (1+Y)) = \log (1+X) + \log (1+Y).$$

How does one see that this formal identity indeed implies the identity above?

We have to see that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{(x+y+xy)^n}{n} = \sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}\,\left(\frac{x^n}{n} + \frac{y^n}{n}\right).$$
Let us expand the term $(x+y+xy)^n$:
$$(x+y+xy)^n = \sum_{i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = n} {n \choose i_1, i_2, i_3} \, x^{i_1}\,y^{i_2}\,(xy)^{i_3} = \sum_{i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = n} {n \choose i_1, i_2, i_3}\,x^{i_1+i_3}\,y^{i_2+i_3} = \sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j\ge 0} {n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}\,x^i\,y^j.$$
We have then
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{(x+y+xy)^n}{n} = \sum_{n\ge 1} \sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,{n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}\,x^i\,y^j.$$
**Now the order of sums $\sum_{n\ge 1} \sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j\ge 0}$ may be changed** (*I will go back to this point below*) to obtain
$$\sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j\ge 0} \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,{n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}\,x^i\,y^j,$$
and we have to see that the numbers
$$c_{ij} = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,{n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}$$
satisfy
$$c_{ij} = \begin{cases}
(-1)^{m+1}/m, & \text{if }i = m, j = 0 \text{ or } i = 0, j = m,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
But we already know that it's true thanks to the formal identity in $\mathbb{Q} [[X,Y]]$, so we are done.

---

The only non-formal step in the above is changing the order of sums. Recall that in the non-archimedian case, we have
$$\sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j\ge 0} x_{ij} = \sum_{j\ge 0} \sum_{i\ge 0} x_{ij}$$
if $|x_{ij}| \to 0$ as $\max (i,j) \to \infty$.

In the above case, we may note that
$$\left|\sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,{n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}\,x^i\,y^j\right|_p \xrightarrow{\max (n,i) \to \infty} 0$$
(*by the way, is it completely obvious?*) so that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,{n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}\,x^i\,y^j = \sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{n\ge 1} \sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,{n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}\,x^i\,y^j = \sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j\ge 0} \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\,{n \choose n-j, n-i, i+j-n}\,x^i\,y^j$$
(we swap the two inner sums in the second equality since they are finite).

---

My question is the following: all these details look a bit messy. Is there a shorter justification of the transition from the formal identity to the corresponding identity with $p$-adic series?

Koblitz in his GTM 58 book says that since in the non-archimedian situation, any convergent series converges after an arbitrary reordering, we can automatically assume that we may write
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{(x+y+xy)^n}{n} = \sum_{i\ge 0}\sum_{j\ge 0} c_{ij}\,x^i\,y^j,$$
for *some* $c_{ij}$. Maybe I am missing something obvious, and the above change of summation order indeed doesn't require any explicit justifications?

Thank you.

Comment: I would try and use that $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ maps $p\Bbb{Z}_p$ into $1+p\Bbb{Z}_p$, and gives a 2-sided inverse to the logarithm. Archimedean  considerations alone would prove the desired identities in the ring of formal power series, no? Proving that $\exp(x)$ is a homomorphism is easier (just a reordering and binomial theorem), so the inverse has to be a homomorphism, too. May be some key link is broken here?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen There is a problem with this argument. exp and log are inverse, but only as functions $B (0, p^{-1/(p-1)}) \leftrightarrow B (1, p^{-1/(p-1)})$. And log is a homomorphism on the whole ball $B (1,1)$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Here is a dumb example: for the $2$-adic logarithm we have $\log (1-2) = 0$, so that $\exp (\log (1-2)) = 1 \ne -1$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reminder! But, wouldn't it be enough for an identity of power series to hold in a smaller ball to imply that the same identity holds in the ring of formal power series?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen That is true, but then justifying this using properties of analytic functions is almost the same as justifying the argument of Prof. Lubin below :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s always possible that I have misunderstood the thrust of your question, but perhaps this argument will satisfy the preconditions you have set:

Set $G(x,y)=\log\bigl[(1+x)(1+y)\bigr]$ and $H(x,y)=\log(1+x)+\log(1+y)$. Take the derivative of each with respect to $x$. From $G$, you get
$$
\frac1{(1+x)(1+y)}\frac\partial{\partial x}\bigl[(1+x)(1+y)\bigr]=\frac1{1+x}\,,
$$
while from $H$ you get, of course, $\frac1{1+x}$. So $G$ and $H$ differ by a $y$-series:
$$
\log\bigl[(1+x)(1+y)\bigr]=K(y)+\log(1+x)+\log(1+y)\,.
$$
Now substitute $x=0$ and get $K=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Fist of all, I must say that I am new to the $p$-adic stuff, and it is great to have you on this website, I have learned a lot from reading your answers. Your proof is very good. I think some authors give the formal power series argument to avoid discussing derivatives of $p$-adic functions. I wanted to understand if the transition from the formal identity is indeed automatic, or requires some thought...

Comment: @AAA: Derivatives are tricky to reason with -- there are lots of locally constant functions, so some function having derivative zero does not imply it is a constant. In particular, I don't believe Lubin's argument is valid at all -- the fact that $G$ and $H$ have the same derivative in the first argument is nowhere near enough to imply that you can write $G(x,y)-H(x,y) = K(y)$.

Comment: @Hurkyl This argument works with some care. See Theorem 8.5 in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf

Comment: @AAA: It's the omission of the care that I'm complaining about.

Comment: The aspect of the question that I was addressing, @Hurkyl, was the formal identity expressing the homomorphism. I think that this is enough to guarantee the truth of the nonformal statement on any set $I_r\times I_r$, where $0<r<1$ and $I_r=\{z:|z|\le r\}$. For this, you need to make use of knowledge of how fast the coefficients of the logarithm grow.

Answer (score 1):

For a shorter proof, the main idea is simple: you evaluate the formal identity at $(X,Y) = (x,y)$ to get the special identity. Everything else is technical detail.

To address a concern in the comments, the point is that evaluation is *continuous*. If $\sum a_k x^k$ is a convergent power series in a topological ring $R$, then any continuous homomorphism $\varphi : R \to S$ will satisfy

$$ \varphi\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k \right) = \varphi\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k \right)
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k \right)
\\= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \varphi(a_k) \varphi(x)^k 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \varphi(a_k) \varphi(x)^k 
$$

In particular, if $\log(1+z)$ is defined in $R$, then $\log(1 + \varphi(z))$ is defined in $S$ and $\varphi(\log(1+z)) = \log(1+\varphi(z))$.

---

The main technical obstacle is the fact that the power series $\log(1+T)$ does not have $\mathbb{Z}_p$-integral coefficients, so we can't directly invoke many of the usual facts about power series rings.

So, one must instead develop enough of the theory of *convergent* formal power series to show the homomorphisms involved are defined and continuous. Unfortunately, I don't recall how straightforward this is; but maybe your source already has the relevant theorems.

Comment: In order to see that $\log ((1+x)\cdot (1+y))$ may be written as some series of the form $\sum_{i\ge 0}\sum_{j\ge 0} c_{ij}\,x^i\,y^j$, one still needs to justify why the necessary rearrangement of terms is valid in the analytic context. I guess my question boils down to that.

Comment: @AAA: I see what you mean; I would be inclined to avoid that issue entirely by arguing $\log((1+X)(1+Y)$ is the image of $\log(1+T)$ under an an evaluation homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[[T]]' \to \mathbb{Q}[[X,Y]]'$, and showing that composing two evaluations gives an evaluation. (where by the prime I mean convergent series)

Comment: @AAA: No wait, I'm making things too complicated. Even in the ring of power series, you still have $\log((1+X)(1+Y)) = -\sum (-1)^n ((1+X)(1+Y)-1)^n/n$. You don't need to rewrite $\log((1+x)(1+y))$ at all.

Comment: @AAA: I've rewritten by post a fair bit.