# On an identity of formal power series (logarithm)

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series, p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

I'm wondering if my proof (attempt) of the identity $\log((1+X)(1+Y))=\log(1+X)+\log(1+Y)$ (on $\mathbb{Q}[\![X,Y]\!]$) is correct.

First, I'm thinking $\mathbb{Q}[\![X,Y]\!]$ as the proyective limit of $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/\langle X,Y\rangle^{N}$. So, in order to show $\log((1+X)(1+Y))=\log(1+X)+\log(1+Y)$, it is enough to show the identity as polynomials, this is,

> \begin{equation}\label{log}
> \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(X+Y+XY)\equiv \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}X^{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}Y^{N}\mod\langle X,Y\rangle^{N+1} \qquad[I]
> \end{equation}

for every $N\geq 1$. In other words, we have to show that the terms of order $\,\leq N$ coincide for the two power series.

First, before showing my attempt, let me explain why I considered it.

Lets start with $N=1$. The RHS of (I) is $X+Y+XY$ which agrees with the LHS up to the order $1$. For $N=2$, the RHS is $X+Y+XY \textbf{$-\frac{1}{2}X^{2}-\frac{1}{2}Y^{2}-XY-\frac{1}{2}X^{2}Y^{2}-X^{2}Y-XY^{2}$}$
which agrees with the LHS up to the order $2$. Here, we see that dealing with the case $N+1$, we can rewrite the LHS in the following way: one part has terms of order $\leq N$, another part has terms of order $N+1$, and there is a part of order $\geq N+1$, but we are only interested in the first two parts, this motivates us to do induction on $N$. So, lets do this. I already showed the case $N=1$, so assume (I) for $N$, and lets check it for $N+1$. The RHS is:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(X+Y+XY)^{n}&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(X+Y+XY)^{n}+\frac{(-1)^{N}}{N+1}(X+Y+XY)^{N+1}\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}X^{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}Y^{N}+\frac{(-1)^{N}}{N+1}(X+Y+XY)^{N+1}
\end{eqnarray}
where the last line is due to the inductive hypothesis. Finally, the only terms in $\frac{(-1)^{N}}{N+1}(X+Y+XY)^{N+1}$ of order $N+1$ are $\frac{(-1)^{N}}{N+1}(X^{N+1}+Y^{N+1})$, and the rest have order $\geq N+2$; in conclusion,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(X+Y+XY)^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}X^{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}Y^{N}$$
up to the order $N+1$, so the result follows.

I'm dealing with the $p$-adic logarithm, I need to show that the identity $\log(1+x)(1+y)=\log(1+x)+\log(1+y)$ holds for every $x,y$ with $|x|_{p},|y|_{p}<1$, where $|-|_{p}$ is the $p$-adic absolute value. This is not so important since the proof is purely algebraic, however, if the identity holds for formal power series, it holds $p$-adically. A different approach I was thinking is first looking at the identity over $\mathbb{C}$, then use the series representation of each side, and invoke the identity theorem to conclude that the coefficients are equal for every $n$, thus the identity holds in the ring of formal power series.

Is my proof correct? Also, is this second approach correct? I've seen a proof of the identity (in the $p$-adics) using [derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392738/p-adic-logarithm-is-a-homomorphism-formal-power-series-proof), however I'm not allowed to use it, since is not part of the book.

Any comment, suggestion, correction is appreciated; thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nice idea but your induction doesn't work. The inductive hypothesis gives that the sum of the first $N$ terms of the LHS is equal to the sum of the first $N$ terms of the RHS $\bmod (X, Y)^{N+1}$ but in the inductive step you need to know what is happening $\bmod (X, Y)^{N+2}$. Your proof "proved too much": note that if it worked it would've worked with $XY$ replaced by any sum of higher-order terms whatsoever, since you could've started the induction at $N = 1$.

Using the identity theorem over $\mathbb{C}$ will work fine. For a purely algebraic proof I would take the formal derivative of both sides in $X$; it's not hard to show from the power series definition that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \log \left( (1 + X)(1 + Y) \right) = \frac{1 + Y}{(1 + X)(1 + Y)} = \frac{1}{1 + X}$$

and it's very easy to show that the same holds for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \log (1 + X) + \log (1 + Y) \right)$, so from here it only remains to show that the "constant terms" match, which means plugging in $X = 0$ and checking that $\log (1 + Y) = \log (1 + Y)$. I guess this is the same proof you said you weren't allowed to use but this is by far the simplest way to prove a lot of formal power series identities, much simpler than the identity theorem.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your argument of why induction doesn't work. I wanted to prove that $\log(1+X)(1+Y)=\log(1+X)+\log(1+Y)$ by seeing it for each degree/order.
If a take a look at the LHS and consider it at most order $N+1$, I can split into three parts as I said. The first part has at most order N, which by the inductive hyphotesis agrees with the RHS up to order $N$. Since I are interested in seeing the terms of order $\leq N+1$, we only care about the terms of order $N+1$ which is the missing part for the RHS. What am I missing?

Comment: @Camacho: when you say "where the last line is due to the inductive hypothesis," that step is invalid. You are assuming the identity for $N$ and trying to deduce it for $N+1$, and the identity for $N+1$ is an identity $\bmod (X, Y)^{N+2}$. But your inductive hypothesis only lets you do the substitution you're doing $\bmod (X, Y)^{N+1}$, so it doesn't tell you what the terms of order $N+1$ are. I think you got mixed up between proving the identity "up to order $N+1$" (which means $\bmod (X, Y)^{N+2}$) and proving it $\bmod (X, Y)^{N+1}$.

Comment: Go through your argument carefully and run it for $N = 1$. You will find that you are not using the $XY$ term at all.

Comment: Exactly, I'm not using it, because XY has degree 2 ($\in(X,Y)$), and I only need the terms of degree at most 1. That's why it was ignored. Now, I'm thinking about what you mean. I ignored the XY term, however if now I'm with N=2, I need to consider that term, but it turns out that it is "magically"  cancelled. But now, I have the terms $-X^{2}Y, -XY^{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}X^{2}Y^{2}$, which will be cancelled if I jump to the case $N=3$, but then I will have new terms and so on and so on ... In conclusion, the inductive hyphotesis does not allow me to guarantee that "cancellation"? Is that it?

Comment: @Camacho: yes, that’s what I’ve said twice now, the inductive hypothesis is not strong enough for this. If your argument worked it would work with $XY$ replaced by a *different term*, say $10XY$, and that result is definitely false.